# Laravel/Blade: Get iteration index from blade template

Tags: laravel, loops, indexing, view, laravel-blade

I have a view with the following loops

```
@foreach ($displayRooms as $room => $events)
    @foreach ($events as $event)
        @include('partials.event', ['event' => $event, 'room' => $room, 'active' => $loop->first])
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Then i have the following partial view with the following code

```
<div class="carousel-item {{ $active ? 'active' : '' }}">
    <div class="card text-center">
        <h3 class="card-header">Happening {{ $event->upcoming  ? 'Today' :'Now' }}</h3>
        <div class="card-block">
            <ul>
                <li><h3 class="card-title">{{ $room }}</h3></li>
                @if (empty($event))
                    <li><h3 class="card-title">{{ $event->$availMsg }}</h3></li>
                @else
                @if ($event->available)
                    <li><h3 class="card-title">{{ $event->availMsg }}</h3></li>

                @else
                    <li><h3 class="card-title">{{ $event->summary }}</h3></li>
                    <li><h3 class="card-title">{{ $event->start->format('g:ia') }} - {{ $event->end->format('g:ia') }}</h3></li>
                    <li><h3 class="card-title">{{ $event->start->format('m/d/y') }} - {{ $event->end->format('m/d/y') }}</h3></li>
                @endif
                @endif
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What i need is the following

```
<div class="carousel-item {{ $active ? 'active' : '' }}">
```

In order to se the class of active to a carousel item, it has to be the first iteration from the above loop.

How could I go about obtaining the first loop index so that I may set it inside of the @include.

Make sense?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: 5.4, but I actually just figured it out calling the parent method before the first method solved my dilemma.

$loop->parent->first

Answer (score 0):

I actually was able to figure this out by calling the parent method for $loop before the first method call.

```
$loop->parent->first
```